# How much time does it take to translate a manga volume/tankobon?

Tags: one-piece, manga-production

I would like to know how much time does it take to translate a manga volume (e.g. *One Piece*) to another language, for example English or Spanish.

Comment: It depends on your skills. if you just want to translate it and not edit the volume I guess less than a day or at most two days.

Comment: I'd assume the question is about the official manga volume, not a scanlation? Though, I'm not sure there is a definite answer because each licensor may have different policy. Related: [Why does it take so long for the English version of tankoubon volumes to be released?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/30909/2516)